# Calculate next cron run date in PHP

Tags: php, cron

To preface this, I know cron-expression library exists.  But I only need this one tiny bit for a quick display in a table in PHP.  Also the library needs php 7.1 and I have to implement this on a php 5.3 site that doesn't really have composer set up.

So given this cron schedule

`00 00 02,06,10,14,18,22 * * *`
How do I calculate the next run date based on the current date?

I found another answer here on SO and it was working until it encountered the multiple explicit hours.

```
function calculate_next_cronjob($cronjob, $elementpositions)
{
    $wildcard = false;
    $elements = preg_split('/[^\d*]+/', $cronjob);
    foreach (preg_split('/[^a-z]+/i', $elementpositions) as $key => $element) {
        $value[$element] = $elements[$key];
        switch ($element) {
            case 's':
                if ($value[$element] == '*') {
                    $value[$element] = date('s') + 1;
                    $wildcard = true;
                }
                break;
            case 'i':
                if ($value[$element] == '*') {
                    $value[$element] = date('i') + ($wildcard === true ? 0 : 1);
                    $wildcard = true;
                }
                break;
            case 'H':
                if ($value[$element] == '*') {
                    $value[$element] = date('H') + ($wildcard === true ? 0 : 1);
                    $wildcard = true;
                }
                break;
            case 'd':
                if ($value[$element] == '*') {
                    $value[$element] = date('d') + ($wildcard === true ? 0 : 1);
                    $wildcard = true;
                }
                if (intval($value[$element]) == 0) {
                    $value[$element] = 1;
                }
                break;
            case 'm':
                if ($value[$element] == '*') {
                    $value[$element] = date('m') + ($wildcard === true ? 0 : 1);
                    $wildcard = true;
                }
                if (intval($value[$element]) == 0) {
                    $value[$element] = 1;
                }
                break;
            default:
                unset($value[$element]);
        }
    }
    $cy = date('Y');
    $ny = $cy + 1;
    if (time() < mktime($value['H'], $value['i'], $value['s'], $value['m'], $value['d'], $cy)) {
        $value['Y'] = $cy;
    } else {
        $value['Y'] = $ny;
    }
    return date('Y-m-d H:i', mktime($value['H'], $value['i'], $value['s'], $value['m'], $value['d'], $value['Y']));
}
```

I imagine this function can be modified to account for this.  I need help making those modifications.

Thank you

Comment: The DateTime Class extension dt (https://github.com/jspit-de/dt) has also a method nextCron(). It is a one file version,  run under PHP 5.3.8 .. 7.x, need no composer and no external requirements.

Comment: @jspit that looks interesting. I'll give it a try, thank you